# C# - finding first enum in IEnumerable and casting to string

Tags: c#, linq

I'm working in JetBrains Rider and have ran into a warning that keeps appearing.  Consider this situation:

```
public enum ValueEnum {
    A,B,C
}

public class Value {
    public ValueEnum ValueEnum { get; set; }
}

public class ValueWrapper {
    public IEnumerable<Value> Values { get; set; }
}
```

I'm trying to obtain the first enum in the list and convert it into a string.  This code works fine:

```
var format = string.Empty;
if (alert.Values != null && alert.Values.Count > 0)
{
    var template = alert.Values.First();
    format = nameof(template.ValueEnum);
}
```

However I'm getting the *Value assigned is not used in any execution path* warning.  Converting the above snippet into the following:

```
var format2 = string.Empty;
if (alert.Values != null)
{
    foreach (var template in alert.Values)
    {
        format2 = nameof(template.ValueEnum);
        break;
    }
}
```

Yields a *Local variable "template" is only used to capture its name.*

Is there a cleaner way to write this (using LINQ or whatnot) to be in line with c# best practices?

Comment: That's not the enum value as a string.  That will literally be "ValueEnum".  Try `template.ValueEnum.ToString()` instead.

Comment: Neither of your snippets actually look at the first item in the collection. They both fetch the first item, then do `nameof(template.ValueEnum)`, which is a compile-time construct which always returns the string "ValueEnum". So `format` and `format2` always contain "ValueEnum".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you actually want the string value of the enum, and not the literal string "ValueEnum", try:

```
alert.Values?.FirstOrDefault()?.ValueEnum.ToString() ?? string.Empty;
```

(Both of your approaches would have worked, had you changed `nameof(template.ValueEnum)` to `template.ValueEnum.ToString()`, but they are unnecessarily verbose).

Comment: This is perfect.  My mistake, was looking for "A", "B", "C", and the nameof operator was incorrect.

Comment: @MikeMelusky: good that you read visual studio/resharper warnings ;-)